# how to paste two files (columns) to a third file incrementing line+1?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, paste

I want to paste two files using the command linux `paste` ( well any other option will be welcome as well) but incrementing the lines of the second. Better give an example:

file1

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

file2

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
```

I want to create file3 as:

```
a 1
b 3
c 5  
d 7
e 9
f 11
```

Comment: Is there really a space between each line?

Comment: That is what I was hoping, makes it simpler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `awk` to print only the odd lines in file two:

```
$ awk 'NR%2' file2 | paste -d' ' file1 -
a 1
b 3
c 5
d 7
e 9
f 11

# Using process substitution 
$ paste -d' ' file1 <(awk 'NR%2' file2)
a 1
b 3
c 5
d 7
e 9
f 11
```